# "Is there any truth TO the stereotype?" or "Is there any truth IN the stereotype?"

Tags: prepositions, difference

I have seen interview and there was a question about stereotype. So I want to ask you which is correct? And why?

> Is there any truth TO the stereotype?

or

> Is there any truth IN the stereotype?